# How to pick the text Thank you for Signing up through Xpath in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have used the below xpath to fetch the text "Thank you for signing up"

```
Xpath : By.xpath("//span[@class='lblMessageSignup']")
```

or

```
"//div[@class='SignupContent']/span"
```

and used the gettext method to fetch the text but its not working.

What is the correct xpath to fetch it?

[image: Screenshot for reference]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: Use `id` for locating a web element.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use `"//*[@id='lblMessageSignUp']/text()"`

Answer (score 0):

You have mentione wrong xapth there is no xpath  it's ID with in Span tag

Use below line of code driver.findelement(By.id('lblMessageSignUp').gettext()